# DeepSORT on MOT20 dataset

Tags: python, tracking

I am trying to use DeepSort for multiple object tracking on MOT20 dataset and can't understand how to utilize DeepSort from GitHub repo. What steps should be performed and how to use det.txt files?

I tried first to use generate_detections.py file to generate detections:

```
python generate_detections.py --model ../../resources/networks/mars-small128.pb --mot_dir ../../MOT20/train --output_dir ../../resources/
detections/MOT20_train
```

but got en error:

> KeyError: "The name 'net/images:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'net/images', does not exist in the graph."

Thanks in advance.